# incompatible types using list.addElement(JOptionPane.showInputDialog();

Tags: java, joptionpane

I'm trying to store this part in a variable so I can use cancel button..
(using java,netbeans)

```
String a = list.addElement(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"your name",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION));
```

this part of code takes the name that user want to insert and adds it in a `Jlist`.
but I'm having the error `"incompatible types required String found void"`

Comment: Show us more source code: where did you declared variable `list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a check for the return value from `showInputDialog`:

```
String result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"your name",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
if (result != null) {
   list.addElement(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting `addElement()` to return ? Looks like a `void` (i.e. nothing) to me.

It's very unlikely that adding something to `list` will return something (depending on what `list` really is). I suspect you'll simply have to get the added value by looking at the last element on the list once you've added it (or simply store a reference to the element prior to addition)

(is `list` a `JList` ? I suspect you've got a [DefaultListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#addElement%28E%29) there)

Comment: addElement() returns the name that the user gives , in my list. Without addElement() works. but i need it to store the name at the list..

Comment: Then take the result, stick it in a variable and add that variable to the list

Answer (score 0):

The `addElement` method will probably not return a `String`.

You probably want the code without the `list.addElement()`. That way it will compile.

Comment: Then just do list.addElement(a);